# How can I use Spring 3.2.3 JavaConfig to read an environment variable?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use Spring 3.2.3 release JavaConfig in my app and I need to read the value of an environment variable.

I have read the [JavaConfig 1.0.0.M4 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/spring-javaconfig-reference.html#externalizing-values) which seems to be exactly what I need but cannot find how to import or resolve the referenced `@EnvironmentValueSource` or `@ExternalValue` annotations.

Can someone show me how to do this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [@Value](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation with a SpEL expression to retrieve the environmental variable from the `systemEnvironment` properties object, e.g.:

```
@Value("#{ systemEnvironment['MY_PROPERTY'] }")
private String myProperty;
```

If you need a system properties, use `systemProperties['MY_PROPERTY']` instead.

Additionally, the documentation you should be looking at is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) - what you have linked to is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Springs [EnvironmentAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware.html) interface:

```
public class ClazzWithEnvironmentInfo implements EnvironmentAware{

    private Environment environment;

    private String getSomeProperty(){
        return environment.getProperty("SOME_ENV_PROPERTTY");
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```